# How to remove in-memory cached table in postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I want to know how to remove the cached table in the memory of postgres. We have done using pg_prewarm, is there is any other way to remove the table from in-memory cache of postgres without restarting the postgres.

Comment: No, not possible. But what is the problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: I cached the DB table which is 500G causing the problem.